# Split element on with text and cast as float on one line

Tags: python, split, floating-point

I am trying to split a string of text on white space and save as seperate variables.  For example, I want to split (lets call it `coord`):

```
472516.93296986789 4100636.8555205753
```

I also want to cast both variables as float.

I know this works:

```
x,y = coord.split()
        x=float(x)
        y=float(y)
```

But I really want to do it all on one line.  Any ideas?

Comment: `x, y = map(float, coord.split())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
x, y = [float(s) for s in coord.split()]
```

You can also use `map()` or a generator expression on the right side:

```
x, y = map(float, coord.split())
x, y = (float(s) for s in coord.split())
```